# How to make the git head of a branch reset to tag on the branch?

Tags: git

I tagged my master branch with a `git tag -a 1.0.0` and I would like to do is reset my master branch with `reset --hard` to the commit that the tag points to. My questions.

1. How to find out the commit id that a tag points to?
2. How to reset the head of a branch to the commit pointed to by a tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just pass the tag name to `git reset` to reset to the commit pointed to by that tag name: `git reset --hard 1.0.0`.

If you still want the commit hash, you can get it with

```
git show -s --format=%H 1.0.0^{commit}
```

(`git show 1.0.0` will also do; the above dumps only the commit hash.)